# How to get current location latitude and longitude periodically .

Tags: android, service

In my application uses current location lat,long. which is periodically update in every 5min. and run in background,means when i launch my application a pop up comes and ask for "do you want to use current location" if i press "yes" then service will be run on background of application and use current location lat long,means refreshing in every 5 min,so how to do it.How to make such service.

Please explain in detail as i am new in android .
every help would be appreciated
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Handling location updates in user-friendly and power-efficient way is no trivial task.

I highly recommend you read Reto Meier's [`A Deep Dive Into Location`](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html) (and the [second part](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location-part-2-being.html)).

**Update**

There is a simple (and wrong) way to do it: set AlarmManager to wake your service every 5 min which requests the location.

This is wrong for several reasons. To do it right first answer yourself this questions:

1. Do you need location updates exactly every 5 minutes?
2. Even if your app is not active?
3. Even if phone is in sleep mode?
4. Even if phone is not moving for longer period (e.g. user is sleeping)?
5. What accuracy do you need? 10m or 300m?
6. Do you need GPS accuracy on all locations? GPS drains battery in matter of hours.
7. Do you need updates if user is moving fast? 5 min in a car can mean 10 miles easily.

Comment: hi peter you recommend me so typical solution i am new in android thats why i post here for getting appropriate soln. but i cant understood above your links..anyway thanks an welcome if you have any other solution.

Comment: hi peter ,can i make a service class and use timer.schedule() for run the service in some time intervals and define service class in my manifest.by using this my code run automaticcally in required time interval and able to get current lat long ?

Comment: This is not good practice, as in this case service would have to run all the time - this is hard to achieve as OS kills services when needed and also service does not run when phone is in sleep mode. Use AlarmManager as advised. Also you do not need to do this when your app is not active.